# Anything else I can do to promote growth?

Tags: identification, diagnosis, plant-health, indoors, plant-care

I bought this plant some time ago, but I’ve noticed that it’s not looking that great. I decided to replant it with new soil since the original soil’s garbage.

I decided to take a picture of the plant and the roots. The roots and the way the plant was cut is really odd...

This plant is usually indoors.

What’s the name of this plant?

Is there anything else I can do to promote its growth?

Does the plant look healthy?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's a Dracena.  Get it in some nice potting mix with lots of drainage.   The roots will take off with time.   For the time being, don't fertilise.   Also when you water it remember the size of the roots.  Little roots can't take up a huge pots worth of water.  You want the soil to have plenty of air for the roots to breath.  If you water log them with too much water you will starve them of air.   So, for the time being only water around the trunk, where the roots are when you pot it up, not the entire pots.  But, you need to keep a close eye one the potting mix.  It will not like being completely dry.  Water it when the soil is still slightly moist, but no longer wet.   I suspect the other soil was too dense, it lacked drainage.  Make sure you buy potting mix or grow mix, don't buy soil.  Both Potting Mix and Grow Mix will have something like perlite mixed in with the brown matter, normally peat or coconut coir. This perlite will give the roots pockets of air to breath.  It will also help the mix to dry out quicker.  Your last planting blend probably lacked the appropriate drainage, so it kept the roots too wet.   That is assuming you watered the plant.  It's a fairly fast growing plant, so once roots start growing you will need to water more often.

Comment: I have one that is about 10 th generation ; started in 1963 from a 6" length of bare stem. They are pretty hardy . When it gets too tall ,like 6 ft. I cut off a few feet and root it to give away.

Comment: @blacksmith37 do you have anything else you want do add.  Did I leave something out, or explain it all clearly enough or anything.  I do appreciate it.

Comment: As you say don't fertilize now,  After it is growing a little fertilizer would be an option.